# Не работает событие click в jQuery при клике на li

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть какой то список

```
<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Есть `Javascript`:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
alert('нажатие!');
});
```

И `.click` работать не хочет, но если выставть `$(ul).click` то все работает. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Да [работает же всё](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/67pQh/). Может, конфликтует jQuery с другими библиотеками? В консоли никаких сообщений об ошибках?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Данные подгружаются с помощью `AJAX` и использование

```
$(document).on('click','ul li', function(){
    alert('нажатие!');
});
```

**ПОМОГЛО.**

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно.

```
$("#elem").click(func);
```

Причем тут Ajax и изменение click на on.

Подключайте ваш js файл с этой функцией в конце html, а не в head и все будет работать.

Comment: прочитайте внимательнее вопрос, либо добавьте больше деталей в ваш ответ